# UIButton action to hide and show UISplitViewController in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I used Split view controller in my app which is for portrait mode. If I **swipe from left to right**, primary view controller is showing. Then, if I click anywhere outside the primary view controller [i.e., Detail view controller], Primary view gets hidden with animation. Its woking fine for me.

But, what exactly I need is, if I click **back button [which is on top of primary view controller (left bar button)]**, primary view controller should be hide and if I click **menu button [which is on top left of detail view controller]**, primary view controller should be Show. I dont know how to do that?

My Coding is below:

```
@IBAction func masterBackButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        println("SPLIT HIDE") //WORKING
        //NOT WORKIN
        var split_Obj = splitVC()
        split_Obj.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryHidden
    }

@IBAction func menuButton(sender: UIButton) {

        println("SPLIT SHOW") //WORKING

        //NOT WORKIN
        var split_Obj = splitVC()
        split_Obj.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverLay 
        }
```

Comment: what is the function `splitVC` doing?

Comment: Hi fabian,, SplitVC is UISplitViewController's class.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it a typealias for `UISplitViewController`? Or do you create an instance of `UISplitViewController` in there?

Comment: yes. SplitVC is UISplitViewController sub class. **split_Obj** , I created instance for that.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. So I hv tried like that.

Comment: But then `splitVC()` creates a new instance that you never display?

Comment: That is, UISplitViewController class name. In story board, v have UISplitViewController know, for that, this class file is added.